# How to design this layout using Relative or Linear layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Hi I am creating weather widget application. I have completed programming part. I am not familiar with layout design. please help me how to design this layout. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: You can create this layout using LinearLayout and RelativeLayout both but according to me use LinearLayout..

Comment: okay inside linear layout, I have to divide into two part in horizontal way. and first part into vertical way. how can I do? please explain me

Comment: Use a LinearLayout for the whole thing, then use 2 nested horizontal LinearLayouts to achive the bottom and the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is exactly what u want now give marging all widget according to your need....

Answer (score 2):

Follow like this:

```
LL(Ver)
    LL(Hor)
        LL(Ver)
            TV
            TV
        FL
            IV (match_parent for height and width)
            TV (wrap_content for both)
    LL(Hor)
        TV (weight = 1)
        TV (weight = 1)
        TV (weight = 1)
```

LL: LinearLayout
TV: TextView
FL: FrameLayout
IV: ImageView

Answer (score 1):

Do it following way
create root LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout 1
    orienation should be vertical dont close it >

<LinearLayout 2
     orientation should be horizontal for adding upper row dont close it to >

<LinearLayout 3
     orientation should be vertical to add 2 textview
     add 2 textview inside it close it />

<LinearLayout 4
     orientation again should be vertical to add textview and image view
     add textview and imageview to it and close it />

Now close LinearLayout 2 />

<LinearLayout 5
      orienation should be horizontal to add 3 textview
      add them inside this LinearLayout and close it />

Then close LinearLayout1 your root LinearLayout />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code, it'll works properly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="New Text" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="New Text" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="New Text" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="New Text" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="New Text" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="New Text" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```